# Compare & Match Nested JSON Values

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq

I am trying to create a function that will compare nested values in a JSON list. 
It needs to compare the values of final.model to current.model. When the model matches it needs to subtract current.qty from final.qty, and remove any models from the list where qty=0.

I've tried this many different ways but have been unable to compare the models in final with the models in current.

```
{"final": [
    {"model": "RRUS-11", "qty": "4"},
    {"model": "RFS ATM192012-0", "qty": "2"},
    {"model": "WCS-IMFQ-AMT-43", "qty": "8"},
    {"model": "SBNHH-1D65A", "qty": "9"} ], 
"current": [
   {"model": "SBNHH-1D65A", "qty": "6"},
    {"model": "RRUS-32 B2", "qty": "4"},
    {"model": "WCS-IMFQ-AMT-43", "qty": "6"},
    {"model": "RRUS-11", "qty": "4"} ]
}

public class Container
        {
            public string model { get; set; }
            public int? qty { get; set; }
        }

var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Container>>>(requestBody);

var DetermineProposed = results.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Key))
        .Select(x => new { x.Value })

        .ToList();

return new OkObjectResult(DetermineProposed);

This is what the returned DetermineProposed should look:
[ {"model": "WCS-IMFQ-AMT-43", "qty": "2"},
  {"model": "SBNHH-1D65A", "qty": "3"} ]
```

Comment: JSON is a string. Once you parse it, you're no longer dealing with JSON. In your case you aren't even comparing the contents of the `final` and `current` keys. You have to extract those contents before you can compare them

Comment: Use a custom IComparer<T>.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a string. Once you parse it, you're no longer dealing with JSON. The current code doesn't even retrieve the two lists, much less compare them.

Calculating the *difference* in quantities can be done with LINQ and joining the two lists based on the model :

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Container>>>(json);

var final=results["final"];
var current=results["current"];

var diffs=from f in final
           join c in current on f.model equals c.model
           let diff=new Container{model=f.model,qty=f.qty-c.qty}
           where diff.qty!=0
           select diff;
```

The result will be :

```
model            qty
WCS-IMFQ-AMT-43  2 
SBNHH-1D65A      3
```

Comment: That did it! I knew I was overlooking something simple. Thanks!